# Characteristic Function limit to 0

Tags: limits, random-variables, exponential-function, characteristic-functions

When calculating the limit of the following characteristic function

$$ \frac{1}{n+1}\left[ \frac{1-\exp\left( \left(n+2  \right)it \right)}{ 1-\exp(it) } \right]$$

and taking its limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ I have found its value equals to 0, since the complex exponential is a function valued between -1 and 1.

How can I interpret the random variable that has this limit characteristic function?

Comment: E.g. for $t=0$ the term $$\frac{1-\exp((n+2) \imath t)}{1-\exp(\imath \, t)}$$ is not even well-defined.

Comment: Perfect.. then since it is not a continuos  function for t=0.... this is not a characterisct function....

Answer (score 0):

I guess the formula comes from the summation of $e^{ijt}$, but this is not valid if $e^{it}=0$. 
Let us call for $t\notin 2\pi\mathbf Z$, 
$$\varphi_n(t):=\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1- \exp\left( \left(n+2  \right)it \right)}{1-\exp(it)}.$$
The limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\varphi_n(t)$ exits an is equal to $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$; by periodicity $\lim_{t\to 2j\pi}\varphi_n(t)=\frac{n+2}{n+1}$.

Note that if $t\notin 2\pi\mathbf Z$, then 
$$\left|\varphi_n(t)\right|\leqslant \frac 2{(n+1)|1-\exp(it)|},$$
therefore, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(t)=\begin{cases}
1&\mbox{ if } x \in 2\pi\mathbf Z;\\ 
0 &\mbox{ otherwise.}     
\end{cases}      $$
Since the pointwise limit is not continuous, this cannot be a characteristic function.